# Kernel Module memory access

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm new to kernel modules and currently experimenting with it.
I've read that they have the same level access as the kernel itself.

Does this mean they have access to physical memory and can see/overwrite 
values of other processes (including the kernel memory space)?

I have written this simple C code to overwrite every memory address but it's not doing anything (expecting the system to just crash, not sure if this is touching physical memory or it's still virtual memory)

I run it with `sudo insmod ./test.ko`, the code just hangs there (because of the infinite loop of course) but system works fine when I exit manually.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    unsigned char *p = 0x0;
    while (true){
      *p=0;
      p++;
    }

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Note that this will also remove the running kernel image, so it will stop before it erases all memory. It could also very likely ruin some filesystem details. Make a backup beforehand.

Comment: Also, dereferencing a null pointer will cause an Oops and probably unload your module. You might consider starting at `1`.

Comment: but am I touching physical memory at this point, or it's still virtual memory? will the OS still block me?

Comment: You're touching a virtual memory. The C standard states dereferencing null pointer as undefined behavior.

Comment: So how can I touch physical emory then? i'm assume the Kernel Module has a process ID of its won then?

Comment: @Tony If this is a kernel module, then it's physical memory.

Comment: @JL2210: No, that's not the case.  Paging is still enabled while kernel code is running.  On most architectures the kernel *does* maintain a mapping of all physical memory somewhere in virtual address space (the "kernel direct map") but that isn't at virtual address zero.

Comment: @josh: To find the virtual address for a physical address, use `__va()` from `asm/page.h`.

Comment: @caf Thanks. Nice to know.

Answer (score 3):

Kernel modules run with kernel privileges (including kernel memory and all peripherals). The reason why your code isn´t working is, that you don´t specify the `init` and `exit` module. So you can load the module, but the kernel doesn´t call your methods.

Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/markmester/skeleton-kernel-module/blob/master/module-skeleton.c) example for a minimal kernel module. [Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-hacking/routines-init-again.html) you will find some explanation about the needed macros.

Comment: __init and __exit are new ways of calling them, you can still use the old way of using `init_module` and `cleanup_module`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I checked it with a newer version of Linux modules.